Difference between google cloud default service account and service agent?
I am not completely clear between the difference and the purpose of default service accounts and service agents in google cloud. From the documentation:
Default Service Accounts:

Default service accounts are user-managed service accounts that are created automatically when you enable or use certain Google Cloud services. These service accounts let the service deploy jobs that access other Google Cloud resources. You are responsible for managing default service accounts after they are created.

Service Agents:

Some Google Cloud services need access to your resources so that they can act on your behalf. For example, when you use Cloud Run to run a container, the service needs access to any Pub/Sub topics that can trigger the container.

Bsed on the above, both of them are used by Google services. And, I understand the following differences/similarities between them:

Both are created automatically
Service agents are managed by Google whereas Default Service Accounts are managed by end user
Service agents are not created in user projects and are not visible (at least with default settings) in the IAM page and cannot be accessed directly as opposed to Default Service Accounts
If an application runs in a Google Cloud environment that has a default service account, the application can use the credentials for the default service account to call Google Cloud APIs

I also see that, according to the documentation, the Default Service Accounts are associated with specific services (App Engine, and any Google Cloud service that uses App Engine AND Compute Engine, and any Google Cloud service that uses Compute Engine).
Keeping in mind the above points, I am not sure I understand the need for user managed service accounts, default service accounts and service agents:

User managed service account: for use by user applications
Default service account: for use by Google services themselves and also by user applications
Service agent: for use by Google services themselves (for example for GKE to launch VMs)

Why have default service accounts? Seems their scope can be covered by either user managed service accounts or service agents. Or is my understanding incorrect and default service accounts are only used by user applications that run for example, on a VM, in which case they are more of a convenience feature?

The difference is the ownership. (User|Default) Service Accounts are owned by you(r Project). You(r code) may use these Service Accounts. Often, the Default Service Accounts are good for boot-strapping but you should create your own, more specific (IAM role) accounts to use in production. Service Agents are owned by Google. Google uses these Service Accounts to effect behavior in your projects' resources.

@DazWilkin: Thanks, so default service accounts are good for boot-strapping, which makes sense, essentially they are user managed service accounts created automatically with certain default roles. Where my doubt remains is that, the documentation suggests that default service accounts are used not just by user applications but also by the Google service itself. I assume that this is wrong then, and that the default account is used solely by user applications (cont. in next comment).

@DazWilkin: So, for GCE for eg., there is a default compute engine service account and also the compute engine service agent. If I were to delete the default account for the compute engine, or for any other service, it should not affect the service itself but only the ability of user applications to access other resources since the service itself would only be using the service agent.

If you delete e.g. the default Compute Engine Service Account (which you can do), you may run into problems. The first is if that Service Account has been used elsewhere (including in another project; this is unlikely but I think it's possible). The second is that the account is assumed to exist and can cause problems if it doesn't e.g. creating new instances without specifying the Service Account. I don't know this but I would guess (!) that there's an organizational hardening mechanism that disables default Service Account accounts.

That is one of questions or doubts I guess. If deleting a default service account can cause problems (not just for the user applications) when it is not shared with other projects etc., it implies that it is being used by the service itself. So the service uses the default account and the service agent. What then is the difference between the scope of these two accounts (one user managed and the other google-managed) in terms of how the service is using them? Why have the same concern being handle by two different mechanisms?

I think the original question has been answered. Specific services don't depend on the default service accounts. The platform and the services may assume the existence of default service accounts. Defaults are used extensively in software and deleting defaults leads to potential problems. I sense your new question is how to disable default service accounts across the platform and, I think (don't know) that this is not possible. Deleting default service accounts will effect the same result just be wary of the consequences.


“Difference between google cloud default service account and service
agent?”

Comment mentioned by DazWilkin is correct.User or Default  Service Accounts are owned by your Project. You can  use these Service Accounts. But you should create your own, more specific  IAM role accounts to use in production. Service Agents are owned by Google. Google uses the Service Accounts to affect behavior in your projects' resources.
As per this official doc

User-managed service accounts are  Service accounts that you create and manage. These service accounts are often used as identities
for workloads.
Default service accounts are User-managed service accounts that are created automatically when you enable certain Google Cloud
services. You are responsible for managing these service accounts.
Service agents are Service accounts that are created and managed by Google Cloud, and that allow services to access resources on your
behalf.

This official document describes how service accounts work with Compute Engine.

As per this When you set up an instance to run as a service account,
you determine the level of access the service account has by the IAM
roles that you grant to the service account. If the service
account has no IAM roles, then no resources can be accessed using the
service account on that instance.

See this official document about Choose when to use service accounts
